# VHDL - signal port mapping issue

Tags: vhdl, hardware, fpga

I have defined an entity with an in and an out port both of type std logic vector.

In the architecture, there's a process running that changes the value of the out port and checks what the value of the in port is.

Now, in my other vhdl file called top.vhd, I am creating several of these entities using the for generate cycle.

What I need is to somehow connect the value of the out port to the in port but I just cannot figure out how to do this.

Lets say that the entity in my first .vhd file looks like this :

```
entity testt1 is

   Port ( 
      var_in     : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
      var_out    : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
   );
end testt1;

architecture Behavioral of testt1 is

.....process that changes the value of the var_out port and checks the value of the in port..... 

end Behavioral;
```

Now in my main .vhd file called top.vhd, after I port map these I need to be able to set the value of the in port to the value of the out port but I just cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

Would be glad for any help.

Comment: Declare a signal of the same type, and when you instantiate the `testt1` entity, use the port map to connect the signal to both ports.

Comment: Thats what I tried to do but it won't let me synthetize for some reason although I am not getting any errors.

Comment: But this approach should be okay, shouldn't it? Mapping both of them to one signal so that when the out port changes so does the in port, right?

Comment: It should be OK. If it's not synthesising, you should get reports why not. I'm assuming there is a register in the entity, and a clock signal (not shown). Otherwise you may have combinational loops, which may not work, though those should have been caught when you simulated.

Comment: Just a quick perusal of your entity shows a syntax error on the var_out description (trailing semicolon shouldn't be there).   It shouldn't even compile.

Comment: How about providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) allowing the problem be duplicated. Without enough information all you'll get is speculation based on assumptions.

Comment: The issue is, when I try to connect them both to the same signal, I get a lot of warnings like this : "FFs/Latches, which will be removed" and this "This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process"

Comment: As @user1155120 has said, you haven't received an answer in 10 hours, why not pare down your code to the bare minimum that still shows the problem and post this? I have a feeling that I may be able to help, but that is based on guessing what your code actually is. My idea may be utterly irrelevant.

Comment: @Daeto getting the "trimmed" warning actually means that your VHDL code analyzes and elaborates. The synthesizer just identified some logic which can be removed. This may happen in your case if the output is not used otherwise.

Comment: what about this? : ERROR:Bitgen:4 - The input NCD file "build/fpga/l_out.par.ncd" is not in the
   specified location.  Please check the correct location of the file or view
   the .par logfile to verify its' creation.
gmake: *** [build/l_out.bin] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

you can use arrays for that. For example you want to have N=8 testt1 units instantiated in top module. You will need an array of K=N+1=9 elements to connect everything together.

```
entity top ()

architecture rtl of top is
  component testt1
    port(var_in   : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         var_out  : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
  end component;

  type my_array is array (8 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(3 downto);
  signal var  : my_array;

begin

   var(0) <= "0001"; -- input val to first test1 unit

   GEN_REG: 
   for i in 0 to 7 generate
      gen_unit : testt1 port map
        ( var_in  => var(i),
          var_out => var(i+1) );
   end generate GEN_REG;

   -- var(8) will be output of last test1 unit

end rtl;
```

Comment: I suspect this is the answer the questioner is looking for, but as the question isn't very clear, it's difficult to tell. It's the answer I had in mind, too.

Comment: But why can't I just connect both of them to the same signal? I am using simplified code because the original is way too difficult. Lets say I want to have 25 units, that means 25x4 = 100. I need a 99 downto 0 vector where I will hookup the 4 bits of out and in var of each unit. Don't I?